# Dependency injection and configuration in a Symfony package

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I need to write a package that's going to be used in multiple microservices based on Symfony, and I'm intending to use Symfony 4 as it's released soon. Fabien says that [it's not recommended to use bundles in Symfony 4](http://fabien.potencier.org/symfony4-monolith-vs-micro.html).

How do I load the `services.yml` and `config.yml` files of my package without using them? [This article](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/extension.html) describes how to solve the problem, but it's all about using bundles. Or his words do not apply to reusable packages which need to use bundles anyways in order to hook up with Symfony?

Comment: I understood the "Bundle-less Applications" as not having the AppBundle. Extending your application with other (own and 3rd party) bundles would still be the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrapped the service into a custom bundle and used [the standard way of loading the config](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/extension.html)

Answer (score 0):

u should register it in your src/Kernel.php:

```
protected function build(ContainerBuilder $container): void
{
    $container->registerExtension(new AppExtension());
}
```

'cause the autoloader from the base Kernel looks only for bundle di folders.
more info: https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/using_parameters_in_dic.html

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly you want to create something like a stand-alone bundle, so to say.

The way I would do it, I would add a config file:  config/packages/my_configs.yaml

From this location, the file is loaded automatically.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I guess Symfony needs to find and publish the configs from my package in this case. How do I make it?

Comment: `

The most interesting files are under config/. The main entry points are the empty container.yaml and routing.yaml files; this is where you can add services, parameters, and routes for your project. A default configuration has been installed as well for symfony/framework-bundle under config/packages/. Feel free to tweak installed configuration files or add more for your own needs.` [http://fabien.potencier.org/symfony4-demo.html]  .. The way I'd do it, to preserve modularity, I would not add configs in the bundle itself but in a separate file (check my answer). That file is auto-loaded.